# How do i make mpi4py work with R in this example?

Tags: python, r, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I have a python script running mpi4py and an R script calling the python script's function. The idea is to have the python function make multiple processes, calculate it's payload and return the results of the calculation back to R.

Python Script:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
import os
import pickle
import subprocess as s
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
sendbuf=[]
root=0
v = comm.rank
rank = v
def mpi_func_test():
    if rank == 1:
        vv = v*2
    elif rank == 2:
        vv = v * 3
    elif rank == 3:
        vv = v * 4
    elif rank > 3 :
        vv = "Rank Greater than 3 impossible"
    elif rank == 0:
        vv = 90
    recvbuf=comm.gather(vv,root)
    if rank == 0:
        f = open('temp','wb')
        pickle.dump(recvbuf, f)
        #f.write(str(recvbuf))
        f.close()
        return recvbuf
```

The R script:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(reticulate)
library(rPython)
# source_python("multiprocessing_play_with4.py")
source_python("mpi_play_with4.py")
mpi_run_results <- run_in_mpi_mode()
# mpi_run_results <- parallelize()
cat(mpi_run_results)
```

To Run, i launch R and type:

```
source(my_r_script.R)
```